# Not able figure out the error in Codewars Growth of a Population kata

Tags: python-3.x

I have just tried to attempt some challenges from Codewars. Unfortunately a test out of 106 is failing and I'm not able to find the error since I am new to Python and Codewars.

([see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okyTH.png))

```
import math
def nb_year(p0, percent, aug, p):
    counter = 0
    nw_pop = p0

    while nw_pop <= p:
        nw_pop = math.floor(nw_pop)
        nw_pop = nw_pop + (nw_pop * (percent/100)) + aug
        counter += 1
    return int(counter)


print(nb_year(1500, 5, 100, 5000))
```

51 should equal  50

Comment: Should it be `while nw_pop < p`?

Comment: Thank you MrFuppes, but I wonder why it only failed in one test while rest of them were cleared.

Comment: Please edit the question to include a statement of the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

> This is using a recursive function.
> If the while loop is TRUE it will call back the recursive function until it turns false (which will return the year).
>
> > Take note: on the int on line 4, it will turn any decimals into an int.

```
def nb_year(p0, percent, aug, p, year = 0):
    while(p0 < p):
        year += 1
        p0 = p0 + int(p0 * (percent / 100)) + aug
        return nb_year(p0, percent, aug, p, year)
    return year
```

Comment: I am sorry if I am bad at explaining. But I hope it will help someone who is looking for a solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
def nb_year(p0, percent, aug, p, count = 0):
    if p0 >= p:
        return count
    else:
        count += 1
        n = p0 + p0 * (percent / 100) + aug
        return nb_year(n, percent, aug, p, count)


print(nb_year(1500, 5, 100, 5000))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: This does not solve the issue, in addition, it fails to pass all of the tests.